# select first and last entry for one month

Tags: sqlite

in my sql query I need to get the first and last entry for a month using sqlite here is what I have so far:

```
    select (select max(data) from  entry)as max_data , pressure from entry where data>=date(max_data ,'-30 days' )
```

Comment: Does "month" mean a calendar month or the last 30 days from the current time? What is the desired output?

Comment: month is last 30 days from last record inserted on db . Thanks

Comment: And what if there is no first entry with that exact date?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM entry
WHERE data = (SELECT date(max(data), '-30 days') FROM entry)
   OR data = (SELECT      max(data)              FROM entry)
```

Comment: I need the pressure from the max_data and max_data -30days can you help me ?